# How do I pull all values from PDF?

Tags: c#, itext7

I have a working solution that opens a PDF file and grabs the text. Unfortunately the values that I need are in form fields. I've tried a few ways to get the values but I can only get what appears to be the form name. The key values are correct, but the value received is wrong.

> Key ValueReturned  Company Name iText.Forms.Fields.PdfTextFormField 
>   Phone Number iText.Forms.Fields.PdfTextFormField  Business Contact
>   Data iText.Forms.Fields.PdfTextFormField  Name
>   iText.Forms.Fields.PdfTextFormField

The values in the form fields are not being returned. Is there a better way to do this?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using iText.Forms;
using iText.Forms.Fields;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Class1 {      
        public string pdfthree(string pdfPath) {            
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader);
            PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(document, false);
            IDictionary<string, PdfFormField> Map = new Dictionary<string, PdfFormField>();

            Map = acroForm.GetFormFields();
            acroForm.GetField("Name");
            string output = "";

            foreach (String fldName in Map.Keys) {
                output += fldName + ": " + Map[fldName].ToString() + "\n";
            }

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(pdfPath, output);
            document.Close();
            reader.Close();
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `PdfFormField#ToString()`, you should call `PdfFormField#GetValueAsString()` to get the value of the field.

Full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using iText.Forms;
using iText.Forms.Fields;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Class1 {      
        public string pdfthree(string pdfPath) {            
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader);
            PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(document, false);
            IDictionary<string, PdfFormField> Map = new Dictionary<string, PdfFormField>();

            Map = acroForm.GetFormFields();
            acroForm.GetField("Name");
            string output = "";

            foreach (String fldName in Map.Keys) {
                output += fldName + ": " + Map[fldName].GetValueAsString() + "\n";
            }

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(pdfPath, output);
            document.Close();
            reader.Close();
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought that I had tried that solution but I must have done it wrong. I guess  it's worth trying things twice.